# DNS Problems with .me domain

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, godaddy, slicehost

I recently registered a .me domain through GoDaddy.  I set the nameservers to my slicehost servers immediately, and that change has been reflected in the .me WHOIS since day one.  However, after almost two weeks, still can't look up the site.  Is there something specific to .me domains or slicehost that I'm missing?

Comment: Slicehost looks like a VPS company - why are you setting the nameservers to point to them? Are you running DNS servers for your domain on them?

Comment: Without mentioning the domain name in question, we cannot really help. I hesitate to vote -1 because the lack of info really makes the debugging next to impossible.

Comment: You do not even mention the setup (do you use Slicehost DNS servers or a name server running on your slice?) or the commands you have run (and their results) to test the domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Slicehost - do they provide DNS services? If so, have you added your .me DNS zone to the Slicehost DNS config? If they don't provide DNS services, then you'll need to change your NS records back to GoDaddy and use their DNS service, probably creating an A record for yourdomain.me pointing to your Slicehost VPS's IP.